# How do I type-check this object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I am in a state of confusion on how I would go about type-checking this variable, but I am not able to do it.

What I understand is that this is an object which contains fields, but these fields are written in a obscure way.

The object is called userApproval

Here is the object when I output it to console.

```
{
l8s.restart_trigger: true, l8s.system_scale: true, manager.cleanup: true, 
manager.extend: true
}
```

Now this is the type I am attempting to type to,

```
 export type UserApproval = {
  MANAGER_CLEANUP: boolean;
  MANAGER_EXTEND: boolean;
  L8S_SYSTEM_SCALE: boolean;
  L8S_RESTART_TRIGGER: boolean;
};
```

Is this correct

Comment: Looks like the property name is `"manager.cleanup"`, not `MANAGER_CLEANUP`.

Comment: Can you please post the code that produces this object, not just the console output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the keys of your object are `example.test` so based on that try this types.

```
type ApprovalTypes =  {
  'l8s.restart_trigger': boolean;
  'l8s.system_scale': boolean;
  'manager.cleanup': boolean;
  'manager.extend': boolean;
}

const data:ApprovalTypes = {
  'l8s.restart_trigger': true, 
  'l8s.system_scale': true, 
  'manager.cleanup': true, 
  'manager.extend': true
  }
```